# React dApp - MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, dapps, react, wagmi

I use wagmi hooks

```
  const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    abi: ABI,
    chainId: 80001,
    functionName: FUNCTION_CALLED,
    args: [id, user, indexes, amounts, proofs],
  });
```

[image: and then I get those errors in the console]
[image]

I have no idea what to even look for. This is the first time I work with smart contracts and dapps. I was searching for those particular errors still have no idea.

Please help to resolve it or provide tips of what to look for if possible